# Gcc compile hello.c for c6x

Tags: linux, gcc, gcc4.7

I compiled hello.c program for c6x architecture:
**gcc-4.8 -o hello -march='c64x' hello.c**
But It got an error: **error: bad value (c64x) for -march= switch** 
Seem gcc can't recognize c64x architecture!

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS & gcc-4.8 version.
Thank you!

Comment: So you use `-march=c64x` to target the `c6x` architecture. A quick bit of Googling indicates that the terms "c64x" and "c6x" are either synonymous or closely related. I'm adding this comment in case people think it's a typo in your question (which was my first thought).

Answer (score 2):

`-march=name`
    `This specifies the name of the target architecture.`

But in your case `target is TI (c64x) board` i.e its `arm architecture`. to compile your program for arm architecture you need `cross-compiler`. But you trying to compile on `x86`gcc `native-compiler` with option -march which is different from target target. i.e     "gcc" is a native compiler. In your case it appears you are not working on an ARM host, thus "gcc" will not compile for ARM on x86.

so download the cross-compiler tool chain and then compile your program with your options.

cross compiler for ubuntu is here

http://www.filewatcher.com/m/gcc-c6x-linux-gnu-4.7.1-0.1.20120606.fc18.1.i686.rpm.10801432-0.html